# Object losing its content after modification in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object **obj1** declared in a file, lets say **A.js**.
I export the object **obj1** and copy a local object, say **obj2** to another file, say **B.js**
Now, if I export **obj1** in a 3rd file, say **C.js**, I should have the values of **obj2** stored in it. But it seems that **obj1** is holding the values that it had in **A.js**

```
**A.js**
export const obj1 = {};

**B.js**
import obj1 from "A";

//called from main loop
someFunction()
{
Object.assign(obj1,obj2);
//At this point, the obj1 is holding the value of obj2
}

**C.js**
import obj1 from "A";
//obj1 is not holding the value of obj2 any more.
```

Comment: `import obj1 from "./A";`

Comment: Are you sure `obj1` has been updated by the time you are checking it in C.js?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the obj1 is modified before it is being called in C.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no strict guarantee of import order in Node.JS. Sometimes `B.js` loads before `C.js`, and sometimes – the opposite. But even  if you know for sure the import order, that's not something you should rely on, because it might change in the future.

Second, imports are most likely cached, so by the time you get to the second `import`, it actually imports whatever was imported the first time, – which was the *unchanged* value.

---

Most commonly, exported objects are designed to be immutable. You could implement this approach in the following way:

```js
// defaults.js
export const defaults = { foo: 'foo1', bar: 'bar1' };
```

```js
// merge.js
import { defaults } from './defaults';

export const merge = (overrides) => ({ ...defaults, ...overrides });
// The `defaults` is not mutated
```

```js
import { merge } from './merge';

const result = merge({ foo: 'foo2', baz: 'baz2' });
// { foo: 'foo2', bar: 'bar1', baz: 'baz2' }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make sure to import the updated value?

Comment: I'd say, you're better off changing the approach to immutable exports

Comment: So, it will be like overriding the data every time I use the modified obj1. The idea was to dynamically create it and copy the data of obj2 to obj1 during initialization and then use the modified obj1 for the rest of the coding.

Comment: No, just use `result`, it has been  initialized once, and it has all the data